# Values inside specific parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have text value as below, i need to find all the value between opening `(` just before `array['nosql']` and its corresponding closing parenthesis. There could be space or no space between `(` and `array['nosql']`

Entire Text

```
2118|"((value5  IN('X5','X1','Y1.6','Z2.3','NO23') AND value1  NOT LIKE('%RISP%')) OR ( value5 is null  AND ( array['nosql'] 
<@ type_list AND (array['S4'] <@ value_list OR array['Z6'] <@ value_list OR array['C2.6'] 
<@ value_list OR array['C2.5'] <@ value_list OR array['NO24'] <@ value_list)) AND ( array['no_key'] 
<@ value_list AND NOT array['RISP'] <@ value_list))) AND SL IN 
('FS025','FS028','FS071','FPG01','FPG02','FPG03','FPG04','FPG05','FPG06','FPG07','FPG09','FPG10','FPG12','FPG13','FPG16','FPG17','FPG18',
'FPG19','FPG26','FPG28','FPG29','FPG30','FPG31','FPG34','FPG35','FPG40','FPG32','FPG45','FPG55','FPG56','FPG57','FPG58','FPG66','FPG97',
'FPG32','FPG33','FPG36','FPG37','FPG42','FPG59','FPG60')"|""|"CT"|"{FPG44,FPG09,FPG18,FPG59,FPG32,FPG11,FPG56,FPG03,FPG10,FPG58,FPG37,
FPG04,FPG17,FPG60,FPG66,FS025,FPG28,FPG12,FPG16,FPG07,FPG31,FPG34,FPG40,FPG06,FPG55,FPG36,FPG19,FPG30,FS028,FPG26,FPG97,FPG42,FPG01,
FPG29,FPG02,FS071,FPG33,FPG05,FPG45,FPG35,FPG13}"|""|"XSQC Target"|""|""|"1"|"Active"|""|"Speed ACP_ASiR"|""
```

Need below output since parenthesis `(` just before `array['nosql']` has all below record.

```
( array['nosql'] 
<@ type_list AND (array['S4'] <@ value_list OR array['Z6'] <@ value_list OR array['C2.6'] 
<@ value_list OR array['C2.5'] <@ value_list OR array['NO24'] <@ value_list))
```

I tried regex, but i cant get specific parenthesis, i am getting all parenthesis using below code but i need specific one.

```
re.findall('\((.*?)\)',text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data you could use:

[`(?s)\(\s*array\['nosql'\].*?\)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/8RX3WQ/1)

- `(?s)` [Mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for dot matches newline
- `\(` Match `(`
- `array\['nosql'\]` Match zero or more times a whitespace character followed by `array [nosql]`
- `.*?` Match any character zero or more times non greedy
- `\)\)` Match `))`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SUWY34699)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to extract the data of interest:

`(?<=\s(?=\(\sarray\['nosql'\]))([\s\w\['\]\s<@(.]*\)\))`

- `(?<=\s(?=\(\sarray\['nosql'\]))`. Lookbehind to find whitespace that is followed by opening bracket and `array['nosql']`.
- `([\s\w\['\]\s<@(.]*\)\))` Character class to match whitespace `\s`, alphanumerical values `\w`, square brackets `[` and `]`, characters `<`,`@` and `)`. Finally, match the final two closing brackets `))`.

You can test it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/WaAxkU/2).

---

Python snippet:

```
>>import re
>>str = """2118|"((value5  IN('X5','X1','Y1.6','Z2.3','NO23') AND value1  NOT LIKE('%RISP%')) OR ( value5 is null  AND ( array['nosql'] 
<@ type_list AND (array['S4'] <@ value_list OR array['Z6'] <@ value_list OR array['C2.6'] 
<@ value_list OR array['C2.5'] <@ value_list OR array['NO24'] <@ value_list)) AND ( array['no_key'] 
<@ value_list AND NOT array['RISP'] <@ value_list))) AND SL IN 
('FS025','FS028','FS071','FPG01','FPG02','FPG03','FPG04','FPG05','FPG06','FPG07','FPG09','FPG10','FPG12','FPG13','FPG16','FPG17','FPG18',
'FPG19','FPG26','FPG28','FPG29','FPG30','FPG31','FPG34','FPG35','FPG40','FPG32','FPG45','FPG55','FPG56','FPG57','FPG58','FPG66','FPG97',
'FPG32','FPG33','FPG36','FPG37','FPG42','FPG59','FPG60')"|""|"CT"|"{FPG44,FPG09,FPG18,FPG59,FPG32,FPG11,FPG56,FPG03,FPG10,FPG58,FPG37,
FPG04,FPG17,FPG60,FPG66,FS025,FPG28,FPG12,FPG16,FPG07,FPG31,FPG34,FPG40,FPG06,FPG55,FPG36,FPG19,FPG30,FS028,FPG26,FPG97,FPG42,FPG01,
FPG29,FPG02,FS071,FPG33,FPG05,FPG45,FPG35,FPG13}"|""|"XSQC Target"|""|""|"1"|"Active"|""|"Speed ACP_ASiR"|"""""

>>data = re.findall(r"(?<=\s(?=\(\sarray\['nosql'\]))([\s\w\['\]\s<@(.]*\)\))",str)
>>print(data)

["( array['nosql'] \n<@ type_list AND (array['S4'] <@ value_list OR array['Z6'] <@ value_list OR array['C2.6'] \n<@ value_list OR array['C2.5'] <@ value_list OR array['NO24'] <@ value_list))"]
```